# How could I join 2 collections from 2 different databases?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables in 2 different databases - users and posts. (It just happens to be in different dbs, can't change that) I want to retrieve all users AND all user's posts (count) in ONE collection. So that the end result would look like this.

```
$model->username     // john
$model->fullname     // John Smith
$model->user_avatar  // jsm2m.jpg
$model->user_posts_count // 3  <-- from different database
```

Of course I could first retrieve all users and then in another collection get all his posts count like this...

```
// I don't want 2 different collection like this....
$users = Users::all();
$user_posts_count = Posts::where('user_id', 1)->count();
```

But I want it all to be in one collection (variable) for convenience.

**Users table**

```
id | username |   fullname   |  user_avatar
1      john      John Smith      jsm2m.jpg
2     martin     Bob Martin     jk3i302.jpg
```

**Posts table (different database)**

```
id | user_id |    post_body
1       1        hello world
2       1        howdy yall
3       1        what is up?
```

Comment: Some DB allow you join across DB, MySql is one of them.  You just need to include the DB name  `database.table` and the user has to have access to both databases (obviously).  How you do that in laravel I don't know.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM database.table AS t JOIN database1.table1 AS t1 ON t.id=t1.id` as I mentioned I am not a laravel user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple solution, you can iterate through each user and add the count of posts to a new property on run-time.

```php
$users = Users::all();
$users->each(function($user, $key){
  $user->posts_count = Posts::where('user_id', $user->id)->count();
});
```

**Edit:**

Here's a more performance efficient solution. The below only executes two database queries, where the above executes 1+N queries, where N is the number of users you'd have in your database.

```php
$users = Users::all();
$postsCounts = Posts::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as posts_count'), 'user_id')
                     ->whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id')->all())
                     ->groupBy('user_id')
                     ->get();
$users->each(function($user, $key) use ($postsCounts) {
  $user->posts_count = $postsCounts->firstWhere('user_id', $user->id)->posts_count;
});
```

Comment: While this would *work*, if your users collection has 1000 users, you'll be making 1001 queries.

Comment: Better, but still would prefer `withCount()`, to be honest. It is simpler, cleaner and would actually perform one query only. `withCount()` uses subqueries to compute the count. See [this.](https://implode.io/LKyfHK)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the connection of your `Post` by doing the following:

```
class Post extends Model 
{
    protected $connection= 'other_db_connection';

    // 
}
```

Obviously, this connection needs to be specified in your `config/database.php`

```
'connections' => [
    // 
    //

    'other_db_connection' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
]
```

Assuming your relationship looks like this:

```
class Post extends Model 
{
    protected $connection= 'other_db_connection';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
    }
}

class User extends Model 
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class); 
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve what you need by doing the following:

```
$users = Users::withCount('posts')->all();
```

You will have a new column called `posts_count` in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Laravel, you could reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries which suggests:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
->get();
```

Edit: So you'd probably want to use:

```
$users = DB::table('db1.users')
->leftJoin('db2.posts', 'db1.users.id', '=', 'db2.posts.user_id')
->get();
```

or, if you wanted to select only specific columns:

```
$users = DB::table('db1.users as users')
->leftjoin('db2.posts as posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
->select(['users.column1', 'users.column2', 'posts.column1', 'posts.column2'])
->get();
```

or, for combined users with count:

```
$users = DB::table('db1.users as users')
->select('users.*')
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS numposts FROM db2.posts GROUP BY user_id) posts'),
function($join) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id');
})
->get();
```

Comment: Remember, I have 2 different databases so joins like this won't work I guess

Answer (score 0):

For join table from different database, you should try

```
User::join('database2.posts','users.id','=','posts.user_id')
  ->select('fields you want to select')
  ->get();
```